# Losing SharePoint Site Structure and Layout

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I am having SharePoint 2010 team site with the layout and folders structure based on the requirement of the customer and saved the site as template.

Now when I try to create sub-site using saved template I am losing the structure and it's layout. Can any one help me how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to save that template using "include the content" option?

> When you save your SharePoint site as a template, you’re saving the
>   overall framework of the site – its lists and libraries, views and
>   forms, and workflows. In addition to these components, you can include
>   the contents of the site in the template, for example, the documents
>   stored in the document libraries. This could be useful to provide
>   sample content for users to get started with. Keep in mind that this
>   could also increase the size of your template beyond the default 50 MB
>   site template limit.

Check this article, which will tell what will be save when you perform this action.

[Save a SharePoint site as a template](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template-5a4eb024-d1fa-4681-a4ac-e6bd1e3209ba#__toc247465693)

Comment: Hello Sarwar,  Thanks for your reply.The site has 3 document libraries with some folders containing few documents.I don't no why it's is loosing the site content,Can you please help me to solve this issue